# Processing Software Environment download

Tags: arduino, light, ambient, processing-ide

Can i download the Processing IDE from another source, cause it seem that the processing.org page is already down. If there another mirror page for download the Processing IDE, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](https://processing.org/download/?processing) works for me. Is it down for you?

Comment: Why is it working on me now? Last night i try that page and it's down.. Thanks anyway, it's working now

Comment: It was down yesterday, I don't know why. Apparently they fixed it?